# Sequence of function calls in C

Tags: c, debugging, gcc

I want to see the code flow of a basic program such as below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen("/mnt/myfilesystem/test.txt", "r");
    if(fptr) {
        printf("open successful\n");
        fclose(fptr);
    }
    else
        printf("open failed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I want to see the complete sequence of function calls executed when this program is run.
I tried using strace and ptrace, but they only list the system calls :(
Any suggestions on how this can be done ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: A profiler would tell you this.

Comment: I can't see much else but system calls.

Comment: You should compile with more warnings. Your `close` call makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want [ltrace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace).

Comment: ltrace tells me the system calls executed for this program, namely fopen, puts and fclose. I want to see what functions are called inside fopen(..)

Comment: Neither `fopen` nor `fclose` or `puts` are system calls.

Comment: are you using `-S` option? if not try using it.

Comment: Umm, `strace` lists system calls. You said that wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: @david: I got a little confused between the libc function fopen(...) and the system call open(..). Thanks for clarifying it. 

Now, my requirement. I want to see the steps involved in translation of a logical address to the physical disk address. So I plan to see the code flow from the fopen() function up to the low level disk driver api. This could be something like a callstack on putting the breakpoint at a low level function.

Comment: @Venom: That's going to be very difficult to do, because there typically is no such code flow. It's only very rarely that an `fopen` will require any disk I/O.

Comment: @Venom: have you access to a machine running OS X, Solaris or FreeBSD? DTrace can trace everything including the kernel.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [gnu profiler gprof](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/gprof/) .

Compile it (main.cc) with `-pg` flags:

`gcc -pg main.cc -o main`

Then execute it (`./main`). Your binary will produce a file (`gmon.out`). Then you can get the trace by using gprof:

`gprof main gmon.out`

with your example I get:

```
index % time    self  children    called     name
                0.00    0.00       1/1           __do_global_ctors_aux [9]
[7]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         global constructors keyed to main [7]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) [8]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           global constructors keyed to main [7]
[8]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) [8]
```

this is not much info because your application is not complex.

If you want to trace system calls, try `strace ./main`. The output is long, you'll see all the system calls:

```
execve("", [""], [/* 26 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x877f000
access("", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7748000
access("", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT
stat64("", 0xbfdc4a18) = -1 ENOENT
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT
stat64("", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=6104, ...}) = 0
open("", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT
open("", O_RDONLY)      = 3
....
```

Comment: Hi Perreal. This is not working. I followed these steps:
# gcc -pg filetest.c -o filetest
# ./filetest
This generates the gmon.out file. then I run
# gprof filetest gmon.out 
This only gives the fields which should exist in the log, but not the call sequence.

Comment: The output can be represented as a graph if you noticed. Or try `strace ./main`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not about a call trace, which has been answered, but I think that code contains a bug, which may be why you are asking.

`close` should be `fclose`, to match the `fopen`

`close` is for file descriptors, not `FILE*` which is returned by `fopen`

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typing mistake. I am still looking for the entire call trace though.

Comment: AFAIK ltrace gives the functions called. fopen is not a system call, it is a function. It may be `fopen(... "r")` just calls `open`

Answer (score 0):

Have you access to a Mac, Solaris or FreeBSD machine?

They all have DTrace, and by using the appropriate provider, you can trace pretty much anything you want. If you have access to a machine with one of those OS's, have a look at the dtrace user guide (preferably find a downloadable pdf)

This might give you a script which does give a program trace:

http://www.dtracebook.com/index.php/Applications

or
http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html

Answer (score 0):

compile statically and disassemble.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile for profiling, using `-pg` the compiler automatically inserts a call to a function named `mcount`. This function is provided by a special library, and creates a database of all calls (with from-address and to-address, and a counter).

However, if you provide your own mcount function (be careful *not* to compile that with profiling enabled!) it can do whatever you like.

I've not tested this, and I don't really know what the mcount parameters are (although I'm sure it's not too hard to find out) but a sample implementation might look like this:

```
void mcount (void *to)
{
  void *from = __builtin_return_address ();
  printf ("call from %p to %p\n", from, to);
}
```

You can then use `addr2line` to figure out what function contains what address.

There is a problem though: it only counts functions that have been compiled with profiling enabled, and this *probably* doesn't include the C library functions, such as printf.

However, if your system does have a profile enabled C library then you'll have to be *very* careful calling functions that might then call `mcount`, or else you'll get an infinite loop. One solution would be to output the text manually using syscalls directly, maybe written in asm. Another solution would be to detect recursive calls and return without doing anything, but that'll be problematic in a multithreaded application, or even with signal handlers.